# I would like to enable Flink to read from Pulsar

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, apache-pulsar, pulsar

I’m new to Pulsar!

Now, I am trying to implement these codes( https://flink.apache.org/2019/05/03/pulsar-flink.html ) in Scala. However, I can’t find some classes(e.g. `PulsarSourceBuild`).
How can I do them in Scala? Where should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PulsarSourceBuilder is from [Pulsar](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-flink/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/pulsar/PulsarSourceBuilder.java)

I'd suggest adding this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
    <artifactId>pulsar-flink</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think this is deprecated, so should I not use it?

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pulsar/pulsar-flink

Comment: PulsarSourceBuilder is indeed from that (recently) deprecated lib. Don't know what to use for now. Maybe use the connect API like here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-72%3A+Introduce+Pulsar+Connector

Comment: @DIOHABARA I think they will be replacing it with https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-flink. If I were you, I'd use the deprecated version and wait until it is merged into Flink mainline.